Text in Primefaces Tree cannot be copied
I need the data within the tree to be copied for user friendliness. For some reason the text cannot be selected.
<p:tree id="tree"
    value="#{valid.value}"
    var="var"
    >
    <p:treeNode collapsedIcon="pi pi-folder">
       <p:outputLabel value="#{valid.label}"/>
    <p:treeNode/>
<p:tree/>


I'm only able to select the text when the entire tree is disabled.
I have also tried setting some css components like the z-index, pointer-events, user-select, cursor, etc. yet nothing seems to be relevant.
I'm not quite sure how JSF creates these components since I'm fairly new. I'm pretty sure there's something happening with the disabled state that allows the rendering of the tree to do something else.

This is fixed in 15.0.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/12197
But you can MonkeyPatch your code right now:
if (PrimeFaces.widget.VerticalTree) {
  PrimeFaces.widget.VerticalTree = PrimeFaces.widget.VerticalTree.extend({
    bindKeyEvents: function() {
      this._super();
      this.jq.off('mousedown.tree');
    }
  });
}


That's way better than my workaround was :D
